# Amazon S3: Restricting access to a specific object to an assigned HTTP referrer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understand it's possible to restrict file access to a specified HTTP referrer with a bucket policy, but is it possible to do this on a per-object basis? We want most of the images in our bucket to be publicly accessible; If you have the link, then you should be able to copy and past it into your browser to view.

Our application has come to a point where we'd like to limit some of these images so that they can only be dished out by us from our site. However, I've only seen this functionality through setting an all encompassing bucket policy. Is it possible to set this on specific objects during their lifetime and not everything in a bucket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can restrict to prefix paths and objects. All you need to do is specify the correct rules in the Resource field of your bucket policy. For example:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AddPerm",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/public/path/public-image.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But as you grow more complex in your security requirements, take a look at signed urls and IAM identity 
federation, as those can be more flexible and easier to maintain than bucket policy rules.